# Excluding dump_syms folder from android bundle (.aab)

Tags: android, size, bundle, dumpsys

I have created an Android release bundle. When I did size analysis I can dump_syms folder which takes around 7MB of size. How can I exclude that when I prepare the final release bundle?

[image]

Comment: Did you got the solution? if yes,then post your answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comment this dependency, if exist in your project(**Gradle:app**)

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-buildtools:2.8.1'
```